# Не удаётся вывести в датафрейме самые популярные смайлики в регионе

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

У нас есть готовый датафрейм (за быдлокод извините), который был получен путём парсинга страниц пользователей ВК и вытягиванием из них смайликов из ковидного статуса. В его итоговом формате есть три столбца:

1. регион России
2. смайлик (в формате unicode, df видит его как str)
3. кол-во страниц ВК, которые его используют в статусе

[image: Сырой код c ненужными, позже дропнутыми столбцами text emoji и city]

Главная идея - получить в итоге датафрейм в три столбца: список регионов, самый популярный в нём смайлик (мы определили его по кол-ву использующих его id-шников) и сам смайлик. Пытались сгруппировать по регионам - не вышло, к тому же данные выходят в формате Series. К тому же возникла проблема - в регионе может быть несколько самых популярных смайликов из-за того, что их может выбрать одинаково кол-во пользователей.

**Вопрос знатокам: как вывести один самый популярный смайлик в регионе в формате Регион-Смайлик-Количество?**

Пока остановились на этом:

`xyi.groupby('Регион')['emoji'].value_counts()`

````
алтайский край       :baby_chick:        35
                     :alien:        34
                     :clown:        33
                     :zany_face:        27
                     :sunrise:        26
                              ..
ярославская область  :paperclip:         2
                     :pray_tone1:        2
                     :exploding_head:         2
                     :bell:         1
                     :dove:         1
Name: emoji, Length: 2595, dtype: int64```
````

Comment: ["Что делать с ответами на вопрос?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Как новому участнику форума подсказываю -  выкладывать надо минимальный, но обязательно воспроизводимый фрагмент кода. Что-бы люди могли запустить,посмотреть как оно работает и дать вам проверенный ответ.

По тому что есть могу только сказать - в Pandas есть метод aggregate ( [agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html)),
применяемый после группирования данных,  в параметрах которого можно указывать другую функцию, в вашем случае, очевидно 'maх'. На 99% уверен, что это то, что вам надо, но без воспроизводимого примера - теперь проверяйте сами.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
res = xyi.groupby('Регион')['emoji'].apply(lambda x: x.mode().iloc[0]).reset_index()
```

PS ответ непроверенный, т.к. в вопросе нет воспроизводимого примера данных.